# Using Open Weather Map API in Android App developed using Unity 3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, openweathermap

I am developing a VR application using Unity 3D. It uses [open weather map](https://openweathermap.org) API to access the current weather of a city. The code works fine in Unity when it runs on the windows machine. But after developing it into an Android app and installed into the mobile phone it is not accessing the weather information.

```
IEnumerator GetWeather()
{

    WWW request = new WWW("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+location+"&APPID=e3a642cec13d52496490dfa8e9ba11d3");
   // WWW request = new WWW("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Anuradhapura,Sri Lanka&APPID=e3a642cec13d52496490dfa8e9ba11d3");
    yield return request;

    if (request.error == null)
    {
        Processjson(request.text);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(request.error);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to access the weather information provided by https://openweathermap.org/ through the mobile phone? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell what errors are you getting in the mobile build ?
Have you tried setting up debug statements between those lines to see where your code breaks on mobile ?

Comment: I am not getting any error. it's not just working. mobile app runs all the weather components at once without accessing the weather information in the open weather map.

Answer (score 0):

I deployed open weather API once and had the same problem. You need to allow internet access for your Android build. To do this, go to player settings -> Android settings -> configuration -> internet access -> require. That should allow you to make WWW requests and access the API.

Comment: thank you for your nice explanation. but, unfortunately, internet access -> require is disabled in configuration menu.How can I enable it?